# Is there is a way to intercept/monitor in Javascript that CSS property changed using vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Is there is a way to intercept/monitor in Javascript that CSS property changed using vanilla Javascript? Like for example change of width property:

```
.div {
    width:100px;
}

.div:hover {
   width:200px;
}
```

...

```
<div class="div">Blah</div>
```

Edit: I mean not hover state change, I looking to detect that width **property** of the DIV changed. It might be any other property or any other way of changing properties: For example I did div.className = "div bigBox", where:

```
.bigBox { width:200px;height:200px }
```

and I want to know that height property changed!

Comment: `<rant>`I get really frustrated when people ask "can I do something a framework like jQuery does with 'vanilla' JavaScript?" Of course you can! What do you think the frameworks are written in?!?  Vanilla JavaScript!  If they can do it, you can do it.  If they can't, you may not be able to, but it's also possible they simply haven't found a reliable way worth including in the framework. Frameworks are not magic. They are JavaScript.`</rant>`

Comment: Well, because I don't want to add XXKb to my project just because only jQuery can do that.

Comment: jQuery (and most, if not all of the other JS Frameworks) have freely available source.  If you only need a tiny part of their code, go find what you need and re-use or re-implement it. I'm not frustrated by your question specifically. Sorry if I gave that impression. It was more commentary on the misconceptions people seem to have about JS Frameworks. The whole point is that inside of their library is a whole bunch of 'vanilla' JavaScript.

Comment: @g.d.d.c: spot on, this is one of the reasons that I avoid suggesting frameworks to new users. I am all for taking a shortcut, but you should have a conception of what you're cutting out first - otherwise your "shortcut" might be a "longcut" and you'd be none the wiser. You see this mistaken perception that one writes "jQuery" OR one writes "javascript" as if they are two different things. This isn't related to the OP per se, but you see this misconception everywhere and it is pretty annoying.

Comment: @g.d.d.c you are right, I will investigate jQuery to find that piece of code. Also I would like to know how to do it under jQuery as well, can you help me with that?

Comment: @Chris, agree but not agree, this is all about using Framework calls where I have no bloody idea what is going under the hood vs piece of my own code which I know like my 5 fingers?!

ALL: I'm sorry guys that expression "vanilla Javascript" created this discussion... I just want to know low level mechanisms of if they exist at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up an interval and watch the css property in question:

```
var cssWatchInterval = false;
function cssWatch (element, property, handler) {
    if (cssWatchInterval !== false)
        clearInterval(cssWatchInterval);
    var comp = element.currentStyle || getComputedStyle(element, null);
    var current_prop_value = comp[property];
    cssWatchInterval = setInterval(function () {
        var comp = element.currentStyle || getComputedStyle(element, null);  
        if (comp[property] != current_prop_value) {
            stopCssWatch();
            handler(element);
        }
    }, 250);
};
function stopCssWatch() {
    clearInterval(cssWatchInterval);
}
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/wAtvp/6/

Comment: WOW! Man, that is awesome website! Is this your creation?

Comment: jsFiddle? LOL no! Keep it in mind, though, it is a great way to test ideas, show other people stuff (problems AND solutions), plus it lets you play with the major frameworks (or no framework at all).

Comment: Thank you for you example, it works, but works only with style attribute changes eg with inline CSS, but when stylesheet definition changes, it doesnt detects.... I've tried el.style.getPropertyValue("width"), but I think it is identical to el.style["width"]

Comment: Edited to use computed style instead of inline style... this will work now with CSS class-based changes

Answer (score 1):

You cannot detect a class/width change.

You **can** detect the hover.

```
document.getElementById('divID').onmouseover = function(event) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of polling you may want to look at cssHooks, available in JQuery 1.4.3+

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/